# Rounding error in function arguments

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

My apologies about the very ambiguous title.

I was refactoring some really old (c89 old) C code today and hit a really strange rounding issue.

The old code used a bunch of `#define`s to declare some of the values used in a particular calculation. In refactoring the code I was going to wrap the calculation into more reusable function which accepts the values as arguments, however I hit a rather weird rounding issue under Ubuntu (not the case on Windows).

It might be easier to explain with an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SOMEVAR   0.001

void test(double value) {
    int calc1 = (int)(1.0 / SOMEVAR); // using the #define directly (so an in-place 0.001)
    int calc2 = (int)(1.0 / value); // using the parameter value

    printf("#define: %d\n", calc1); // prints 1000, as expected
    printf("param:   %d\n", calc2); // prints 999 on Ubuntu and 1000 on Windows
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    test(SOMEVAR);  
}
```

Compiled on Ubuntu with the following command

```
gcc -std=c99 -o test test.c
```

I know there's loss of precision when it comes to floating-point arithmetic, but surely this is a problem that can be worked around? I'd really like to encapsulate the calculations into a re-usable function but with this loss of precision in switching from `#define`s to function arguments the calculations are all going to be incorrect.

As an example of what I mean, here's an excerpt of one point in the code where this makes a huge difference:

```
#define DT  0.001
// -- snip

int steps = (int)(1.0 / DT); // evaluates to 1000
for(int i = 0; i < steps; ++i) 
    // do stuff
```

vs

```
void calculate(double dt) {
    int steps = (int)(1.0 / dt); // evaluates to 999
    for(int i = 0; i < steps; ++i)
        // do stuff
}
```

As you can see, the function-ized version will iterate one less time than the `#define` version, which means the results will never match.

Has anyone else come up against this problem? Is there a solution or should I just stop fighting the `#define`, suck it up and work around it?

EDIT: This happens when using `gcc` or `g++` (my refactored version will be written in C++, rather than c99 C, I just used C in this example for simplicity).

Comment: You're asking about C and C89 in particular; please do not dual-tag such questions with C++ too.

Comment: It happens under both C and C++, I merely said the old version of the code was `C89`, my revised version will be in C++ and it has the same rounding issue under Ubuntu.

Comment: Why? It's a legitimate issue under both C and C++, the old version was written in old-style C, mine will be written in C++. If there's a `C++`-specific solution to the problem I'd never get it if I only specified `C` in the tags.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well if the OP is refactoring to C++ then I think adding the C++ tag makes sense?

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like constant folding going on here, if we look at the [godbolt output](http://goo.gl/lIYPwN) for your first set of code, we can see that the first calculation is boiled down to a constant:

```
movl    $1000, %esi #,
```

so in this example the compiler is performing the calculation during translation since both values are constants and it knows the expression is really just:

```
1.0 / 0.001
```

whereas in the second case since both values are not constants the compiler evaluates at run-time:

```
divsd   %xmm0, %xmm1    # value, D.1987
cvttsd2si   %xmm1, %esi # D.1987, calc2
```

So unfortunately the calculation are not equivalent and can in some cases can lead to different results, although I can not reproduce the results you are seeing on any online compiler yet.

If you are going to refactor to C++ and can use C++11 then you can always use `constexpr` to get compile time evaluation:

```
constexpr double SOMEVAR  = 0.001 ;
//....
constexpr int calc1 = (int)(1.0 / SOMEVAR );
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Does this mean I'm screwed and need to just suck it up and use the `#define`s to get compile-time evaluation?

Comment: @JasonLarke I can not reproduce the result, so it makes it difficult to suggest a solution since I can't verify them. What compiler and version are you using on each platform?

Comment: `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3`
`g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3`
`Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS` (running as a VirtualBox virtual machine)

Comment: Also, with `constexpr`, is there any way to hint that to the compiler on function arguments? i.e `void test(constexpr double x)`?

Comment: @JasonLarke you can use [constexpr function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) but the arguments must be constant expression in order for it to be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for all your help:) I can't use C++11 unfortunately, so I might just have to just work around the whole issue.